# JavaFX Force Uniform ImageView Size Without Using Preserve Ratio

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

In the following code:

```
        Text imageText = textX.getTextWithDefaultBoldLookAndFeel("Image:");


        BufferedImage image = (pojo.getImage() != null) ? pojo.getImage() : imageX.getImageFromFileAsBufferedImage(GlobalVar.defaultImage);;


        double maxHeight = 300;
        double maxWidth = 150;

        Pane imageViewPane = new Pane();
        imageViewPane.setMaxWidth(maxWidth);
        imageViewPane.setMaxHeight(maxHeight);


        //Setting the image view 
        Image image = SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(image, null);

        //Setting the image view 
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image); 



        //Setting the fit height and width of the image view 


        imageView.setFitWidth(maxWidth); 
        //imageView.minWidth(maxWidth); // this won't solve the problem

        imageView.setFitHeight(maxImageHeight); 
        //imageView.minHeight(maxHeight); // this won't solve the problem


        // this solves the problem but also enlarges image which I do not want
        imageView.setPreserveRatio(false);


        imageGridPane.add(imageText, 0, 3); 
        imageGridPane.add(imageView, 1, 3); 

        gridPane.addRow(1, imageGridPane);
```

I'm adding Image to `ImageView` which is then added to a `GridPane`. The images I'm adding are of different sizes - some are too small to fill the entire `ImageView` area (300 x 150). When this occurs it causes the parent GridPane box to be smaller than the other boxes. I do not desire this. I realize that when an image is too small I am  able to resize the image by setting `imageView.setPreserveRatio(false);` however, while it creates uniform boxes, it also causes the image to become blurry.

I would like for the image to be displayed however big (up the max limit) or small it is (i.e, not to be enlarged if too small) but I still want a uniform size for all `ImageView`s so that the parent GridPane (box) are all the same size. Perhaps so sort of transparent border can be added when the image is too small so that the image is not enlarged but `ImageView` still takes up same space as other large images - forcing uniform box size. I was unable to accomplish this by setting minWidth and minHeight properties of parent `GridPane`.

How can this be achieved?

Thanks!

Comment: [mcve] please (best with urls to images available in the net)

Comment: See [TilePane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/TilePane.html)